# how to make MVW effective with table field length changes?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, materialized-views

I have a MVW as below which is an existing one.

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ADS.MVW_AGREEMENT (AGR_ID,_AGR_NBR,SRC_DOC_CD,FNL_DOC_RECPT_DT,AGR_SRC_SYS_CD,UHG_REL_IND)
TABLESPACE ADSDATA
AS
SELECT sfa.agr_id,
       sfa.agr_nbr,
       sfa.src_doc_cd,
       sfa.fnl_doc_recpt_dt,
       sfa.agr_src_sys_cd,
       sfa.uhg_rel_ind
  FROM ADS.agreement sfa;
```

In agreement table src_doc_id is varchar2(15). Now if I need to change this field length to 20. When I do that in table and try to refresh MVW, I am facing an error as below:

```
 ORA-12899: value too large for column
"ADS"."MVW_AGREEMENT"."src_doc_cd" (actual: 20, maximum:15)
```

Could you please guide me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to issue an `alter materialized view` to modify the column in the MV exactly the same way you modified it in the base table.

Short example (what you are missing is the fourth line of code, adapted to your situation):

```
create table t ( x varchar2(10) );
create materialized view v as select * from t;

alter table t modify ( x varchar2(20) );
alter materialized view v modify ( x varchar2(20) );
```